# pm2 Startup not starting up on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pm2

I am having difficulty getting pm2 to restart (itself and two node/express files, `app.js` & `app2.js`) on a server re-boot.

Below is the processes I have tried:

```
pm2 startup
pm2 start app.js
pm2 start app2.js
pm2 startup ubuntu (also tried systemd and with/without -u username)
pm2 save
```

I ran the above commands in every possible combination and nothing worked. I tried running as root and it did not work either.

My `~/.pm2/dump.pm2` file contains information so I am not sure where else to look.

I have attempted to modify my `/etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh` file according to [this issue](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1321) but it did not help.

My Setup:
Digital Ocean Server
Ubuntu 15.10
Node v5.4.1
PM2 v 1.0.0

Other references I tried..
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps
https://gist.github.com/leommoore/5998406
https://www.terlici.com/2015/06/20/running-node-forever.html
https://serversforhackers.com/node-process-management-with-pm2
http://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/running.html#starting-node-red-on-boot
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1316

So far, each time I reboot the server, pm2 fails to startup automatically (unless I need to wait a few minutes? - nginx restarts instantly).

Can someone help me out with this? What is the order in which the commands should be run? Do I need to modify any additional files?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to save your node app using

```
 pm2 start [app_name]
 pm2 save
```

Then do:

```
 pm2 startup [operation system]
```

This will create a dump.pm2 file that pm2 needs to run your app on reboot.

Operation system:

- **systemd**: Ubuntu >= 16, CentOS >= 7, Arch, Debian >= 7
- **upstart**: Ubuntu <= 14
- **launchd**: Darwin, MacOSx
- **openrc**: Gentoo Linux, Arch Linux
- **rcd**: FreeBSD
- **systemv**: Centos 6, Amazon Linux

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. Readout from my initial stab at `pm2 startup ubuntu` told me to use `pm2 startup upstart`. Did that, now my app starts up on reboot.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Xenial 16.04. What worked for me was: pm2 save...pm2 startup upstart. Yeah!

Comment: @pwbred it depends on the processes management which ubuntu uses, which depends on ubuntu versions. You may check case specifics here: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Comment: if i manually stop an application `pm2 stop 1`, should it be restarting when the machine reboots if i've done these steps? i thought it would but it isn't.

Answer (score 6):

The solution for me was restarting pm2 with *systemctl*: `systemctl reload-or-restart pm2-root`

When I setup my Ubuntu 18.04 server on the first time, I ran `pm2 start app.js` to start my app. Then when I tried to run `pm2 startup` + `pm2 save` to restart the app on boot, this seemed to be not working, as by running `systemctl list-units`, pm2 didn’t show up in the services list. Even though the app was running (`pm2 list` confirmed that). So I ran `systemctl list-units -all`, and pm2 showed as “inactive” and “dead”.

So I did:

- `systemctl status pm2-root` (just to confirm that it was "inactive"/"dead")
- `systemctl reload-or-restart pm2-root` (to restart pm2 through *systemctl*)
- `systemctl status pm2-root` (to confirm that pm2 now was “active”/“running”)
- Then I also ran `systemctl enable pm2-root`, to enable PM2 to run on startup (not sure if necessary)
- And `pm2 startup` + `pm2 save` again (for the start on boot)

OBS.: I used `pm2-root` in my commands, as I was running pm2 with `root` user, but you should replace for your user (`pm2-<USER>`), if needed.

Comment: same issue. Thank you

Comment: Worked for me as well

Answer (score 4):

I think I [solved the problem](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/903#issuecomment-200338873)

> I played with pm2, and found two working way for CentOS 7 (in your
>   project folder index.js - main file):
>
> - 1
>
>   ```
>   sudo pm2 start index.js
>   sudo pm2 save
>   sudo pm2 startup centos
>   ```
> - 2
>
>   ```
>   pm2 start index.js
>   pm2 save
>   pm2 startup centos
>   '# and run the script generated in the previous code under sudo
>   ```

Comment: I'll have to give this a shot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking your boot logs on Ubuntu ( `cat /var/log/boot.log` )?

You probably see an error like:

`Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/<USER>/.pm2'`

I haven't been able to solve this issue myself but at least this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I checked that file and there is nothing in there :(

Comment: Could it be that the permissions on that folder are too strict?  Just a guess.

Comment: This is the solution to permission issue: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1321#issuecomment-510348227

Answer (score 1):

I know it's pretty old, but here is my version:

1. Start processes with pm2: `pm2 start app_name.js`
2. Save processes in the list: `pm2 save`
3. Generate startup script: `pm2 startup`

Here we'd get the command list.

**One of these commands highlighted with green must be implemented in the next step**

4. **Activate script** (command from the previous step): `systemctl enable pm2-root`

The reason I post this is because I think it is not obvious that this last command is required. But without it startup on reboot wont work.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

The got following codes in Ubuntu:

```
pm2 start main.js
pm2 save
pm2 startup ubuntu
```

Note that "pm2 save" will create a dump.pm2 file in /root/.pm2/dump.pm2 and this one will be used when your machine is restarted.

And if you don't know your operation system name just use:

```
pm2 startup
```

PM2 will detect your operating system automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:‎

1. Move to folder where you installed the PM2 (such as /home/ubuntu).
   There will be ‎a folder ‘.pm2 ‎.‎
2. Run ‘PM2 startup’ to generate an
   active startup script.‎
3. Run ‘PM2 save’ to freeze a process list for
   automatic respawn.’.‎

Now all the processes will auto start on roboot.