# How do you use pm2 startup with a non-root user?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, pm2

According to the documentation here: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#startup-systems-support

You can use the command `pm2 startup ubuntu -u nodeapps` to resurrect all saved pm2 jobs on server startup.

I ran this command as the nodeapps user. Then I was given a sudo su command to run. I logged out of nodeapps, used sudo su to log into the system as root, and ran the command:

```
sudo su -c "env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin pm2 startup ubuntu -u nodapps --hp /home/nodeapps"
```

The processes did not restart on server restart. I found this question on Stack Overflow: [Ubuntu 14.04 - pm2 startup not starting after reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769302/ubuntu-14-04-pm2-startup-not-starting-after-reboot).

In the script `/etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh` I found the line that question recommended addressing:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export PM2_HOME="/home/nodeapps/.pm2"
```

But it looks correct to me so I didn't change anything.

I then found this question: [pm2 Startup not starting up on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821063/pm2-startup-not-starting-up-on-ubuntu)

and in my boot logs I find the following line:

```
Starting pm2
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I know that 'node' on Ubuntu is actually 'nodejs'. Could this be the reason?

If it is, what can I do to make the startup command look for nodejs instead of node.

Alternatively, could this be a $PATH problem? If it is, how can I add the correct path to root (at least I think it should be added to root)

Comment: Creating a symlink on root fixed the problem. `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

In fact that was the problem. Fixed via creating a symlink (as root):

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node
```

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if it will help you but I use in this way:

---

1. As a non-root user

```
pm2 startup -u <YOUR_NON_ROOT_USER>
```

2. Copy line showed like

```
env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin pm2 startup systemd -u delivery --hp /home/delivery
```

3. As a root execute

```
env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin pm2 startup systemd -u delivery --hp /home/delivery
```

4. Back to non root user and type:

```
pm2 start <YOUR /PATH/TO/INDEX.JS> --name <YOU_APPLICATION_NAME>
```

5. As a non-root type:

```
pm2 save
```

6. reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

7. As a non-root user type the commando bellow to check if it works

```
pm2 status
```

---

PS: Change  as needed.

I hope it will be useful for you or someone.

Comment: Didn't need step 4 for Ubuntu 21.04 server. Had the user run step 1, I ran the output and it prompted for sudo. After that they started their scripts, used pm2 save and it worked after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I used a much simpler solution (on my opinion...). If you have SU permissions you can impersonate other users, like this:

```
sudo -u other_user_name bash -c 'pm2 restart server'
```