# pm2 not running next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server, pm2

I have next.js application on an apache server.I was running npm run start in my terminal and it is working as expected, starting build website. problem is that when I close terminal, service stops. I know that I have to use pm2 for that and I have installed it globally, problem is that it is not running.
am trying this command

```
pm2 start npm --name "khulo" -- start
```

my application name is "khulo".
this is the output I get from terminal:

[image]

therefore as far as I understand, there is no process and therefore there is no service on my server. what is the problem? am running that command in my root project

edit: I know that I need priviliges as an user to start pm2, but am not root user, therefore now am asking what privillege do I need as a non-root user to control pm2?

Comment: Where is the project actually ? are you running pm2 command in your project directory ( in which package.json is present ) or in your working directory ?

Comment: in which package.json is present

Comment: I had same problem, issue was that user which is running pm2 didn't have permissions for app folder and files. Did you try running `npm start` as that user?

Comment: yeah, just normal npm start, npm run start, npm run build works just fine

Comment: Have you tried to use an ecosystem file to start the app ?

Comment: yes, no luck there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a nextjs app running with the same command that is connected to the nodejs backend. I start with the sudo permissions by running `sudo su`

```
pm2 start npm --name "khulo" --start
```

To start with the non-root user, try the following link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65461743

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this:

```
pm2 start "npm run start" --name "khulo"
```

More informations: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/

If you need to start as root:

```
sudo pm2 start "npm run start" --name "khulo"
```

Comment: am not root user. 
trying this command: pm2 start npm --name "khulo" -- start using root user works  fine, I just want to know what privilleges do I need as non-root user to be able to run same command without any problem.

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo` as i wrote in my answer?

Comment: privileges needed depends on user that run PM2 daemon

Comment: I cant run sudo as am not super user