# PM2 not restarting npm script

Tags: node.js, pm2

I start my app with the following command:

pm2 start npm --name “my-site" -i 0 -- run runGlobalProduction

But I'm finding that its intermittently crashing and not re-starting, even though when I ls the . processes, "my-site" shows as online. I have to reload my-site to get it to work.

Checking the logs, I can see this error but its not very informative:

> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above. 0|my-sit | ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   0|my-sit | npm ERR! errno 1 0|my-sit | npm ERR! my-website@3.2.4
>   runGlobalProduction: export PORT=8080
>   CONFIG_PATH=config/web/global-production.config.json&&npm run
>   apiServer 0|lmy-sit | npm ERR! Exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your node app using

```
  pm2 start [app_name]
  pm2 save
```

Then do:

```
 pm2 startup [operation system]
```

This will create a dump.pm2 file that pm2 needs to run your app on reboot.

Quite similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821063/pm2-startup-not-starting-up-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks but I have saved already. The problem is not so much when the machine reboots, but when the app itself crashes. PM2 should restart any instance that crashes but its failing